# What does your job level do in Final Fantasy III?

Tags: final-fantasy-3

I have Final Fantasy 3 on my DS, and I don't understand what my job level is supposed to do, or how it works besides it upgrading after battles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[More information about the job guide that you can read.](https://www.gamesradar.com/cheats/13156/) The following information below here will answer your general questions about job levels.

Q: What is Job Level?

A: Job Level (Job LV) is a renewed idea for the DS version. Each character can
   have, at most, 23 jobs, and every Job comes with a Job LV showing how
   proficient that specific character is at that Job. Maximum Job LV is 99.

Q: What does Job LV do?

A: The more you train as that Job, the higher the level will become, and the
   better your character will perform! Here is EVERYTHING that Job LV affects:

1. Number of hits when attacking.
2. Chance of executing a Critical Hit.
3. Physical damage.
4. Black Magic damage.
5. White Magic recovery.
6. Summon damage.
7. Attack Power of bare-handed Monks and Black Belts.
8. It also enhances the special abilities of certain Jobs.
9. In one of the side quests, a Job Mastery Item will be unlocked when a
     character reaches Job LV 99.

Q: What is NOT affected by Job LV?

A: The characters' overall stats are not affected by Job LV. Strength, Agility,
   Vitality, Intellect, and Mind.

Two characters with SAME Job and Character LV, but different Job level, will
   have the same stats.  However, their performance may differ.

Q: Speaking of the Job Mastery Items, can I get more than one?

A: There is ONE item per Job, and you can only get each of them once.  In the
   end you can only have 23 of them.

Q: How does the Job LV increase?

A: Every character has a hidden stat called Job Points (JP) that dictates their
   Job LV growth. When JP is accumulated to 99, Job level goes up by 1. Each
   action (except: Front, Back, Escape, and Flee) will contribute a fixed amount
   of job points to the character.